# opening the privacy policy and terms of service links from the google sign-in dialog

Tags: android, google-signin

I want to open the privacy policy link when the user clicks the privacy policy in the dialog. I couldn't find anything on the documentation. currently, it shows "no browser found to open the link" when the privacy policy is clicked

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Google Cloud Console, then jump to your Project.

In side menu or navigation menu > [Oauth Consent screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/)

Edit or Create app consent and put links there.